# How to read property of Ember.View.extend

Tags: ember.js

I have view on which I defined a custom tagName. I need to be able to read this tagName elsewhere in the program. Is there any way to do this?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oportocala/VDMym/

```js
var MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'section'
});

Ember.Application.create({
    ready: function () {
       alert(MyView.tagName);         
    }
});
​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access an instance variable from a class.
If you access the value from an instance of the view it works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/VDMym/1/

```js
var MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'section'
});

Ember.Application.create({
    ready: function () {
       alert(MyView.create().get('tagName'));         
    }
});
```

​

Also, in Ember you need to use `get` and `set` methods to access variables.

EDIT:
If you really want a class variable use `reopenClass` instead of `extend` when defining the view.